# Number reports per subgroup

Tags: report, ms-access-2007, grouping, page-numbering

I have a table of Premiership Football teams, and another table of their squad. And I have recorded different stats per player per team. So I have two tables:
TEAM
and
PLAYER

```
#      TEAM
1      Man U
2      Liverpool
3      Tottenham

TEAM # PLAYER      SCORED  ASSIST ETC
2      Gerrard       4       5 
3      Soldado       2       7
2      Sterling      2       3
```

The TEAM table has the individual players from each team in a subtable for each team.
From this I have created a report from the PLAYER table to show the players name, team, stats etc. What I do need though is to number the records per amount of records in that team in the report itself, almost like page numbers.
For instance, Liverpool say have 20 players, I would like it show Gerrard 9/20, Sterling 18/20. It is one record per page. At the moment, all I can get is their record number, of all the players in the database, like 9/500.

What is the best way of doing numbering records per subgroup(each team)? I thought it would be more simple but doesn't look like it.

Comment: So I have worked out, a bit silly really, I have simply made a textbox in the report for each record and put    =1  into it with the running sum Over Group. I have also made a query to tell me the total amount of players per team. The bit I am finding difficult now is for each record, showing the amount of players per team, like "20" in 9/20. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It was really simple. I just had to put a

```
=Count(*)
```

in the group header, and named it "groupcount". Then add another textbox and have

```
=[GroupCount]
```

in the record detail part of the report. Then it gave me the total number of records in each group displayed on each record.